# Clojure Multimethods distinguishing a map from a list of maps

Tags: clojure

I'd like to write a function that can process one of a particular thing (represented by a map) or a list of these maps.

Is it possible to use defmulti / defmethod for this? Can anyone point me to an example of how to write the test function for being either a map or a list of maps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multimethods will use class hierarchies automatically, so you can just switch on type:

```
(defmulti process class)

(defmethod process clojure.lang.IPersistentMap [m]
  (println "got map"))

(defmethod process clojure.lang.Sequential [s]
  (println "got sequential"))

(defmethod process :default [o]
  (println "got something else"))
```

You have to be careful in building cases like this to make sure you don't run into a concrete type that satisfies two cases. If so, it's arbitrary which will be picked - use `prefer-method` to define a preference. (Also note that while you can do exactly the same impl as above with protocols there is no equivalent way to pick a preferred result with protocols).

Or you could make your dispatch method arbitrarily clever in detecting the cases you care about:

```
(defmulti process
  (fn [o] 
    (cond
      (map? o) :map
      (sequential? o) :sequential
      :else (class o))))

(defmethod process :map [m]
  (println "got map"))

(defmethod process :sequential [s]
  (println "got sequential"))

(defmethod process :default [o]
  (println "got something else"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
(defmulti foo type)

(defmethod foo clojure.lang.IPersistentMap [m]
  (println "map"))

(defmethod foo clojure.lang.Sequential [m]
  (println "sequential"))
```

However, it may be cleaner to have a single function with a condition, e.g.

```
(if (map? m) 
  (deal with the map) 
  (deal with each map, e.g. by recursing over each element))
```

Comment: Note that there are multiple map classes - (class {}) will be PersistentArrayMap but most maps with > 8 key/value pairs will actually be PersistentHashMaps.

Comment: @AlexMiller you're right. Updated my example to be more generic.